# Display dataTable doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I'm trying to display DataTable in my project, It works only  without Layout 
This is my code Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title Gestion Phosphate</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <! --NAVBAR-->
            <div class="row">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
         <footer>
         </footer>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

And in my view :

```
@model IEnumerable<wb01.Models.Réception_camions>
@*@{ Layout = null;}*@
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <table class="display" id="MyDataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr @*class="active" style="color:blue; background-color:black"*@>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date_d_arrivée)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.heure_d_arrivée)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Poids_cam)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Camions.N_série)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Qualité)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_d_arrivée)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.heure_d_arrivée)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Poids_cam)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Camions.N_série)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qualité.Qualité1)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new { id = item.Id_rec_cam }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Détails", "Details", new { id = item.Id_rec_cam }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Supprimer", "Delete", new { id = item.Id_rec_cam })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#MyDataTable").DataTable();
    })
```

Am I missing a reference or is not in its correctly place, please help; thanks in advance.I tried to change the order of references but I got the same result even with other Views!
Am I missing a reference or is not in its correctly place, please help; thanks in advance.I tried to change the order of references but I got the same result even with other Views!

Comment: The code where you display your table is missing. Please add it.

Comment: I added the code, @Marco

Comment: The problem is when I comment Layout (@*@{ Layout = null;}*@) and execute  the View  I got what I need (Table with paging and search ).But when I use Layout in my View I got a table without border and paging.     I didn't recieve any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiplem problems. You are loading jQuery multiple times. Once in your layout, and once in your view. Remove the reference in your view.
Your next problem is, that you put script tags directly in your view. While this might work, it is probably causing an issue with the way your scripts are loaded.
You should wrap them in `@section scripts { }` block, to make sure, the scripts in your view are executed after layout *and* view are rendered. If you take a look at your layout, you will see that `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` comes after jQuery and bootstrap have been loaded up.

All in all your view should look more like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<wb01.Models.Réception_camions>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">

<!-- html omitted-->

@section scripts {
  <!--jQuery is loaded when this executes, so now we can pull in our jquery plugins-->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MyDataTable").DataTable();
    })
  <script>
}
```